# Get.defaultDialog with ListView.builder is throwing exception

Tags: flutter, height, flutter-getx, flutter-listview, flutter-alertdialog

I am having an `AlertDialog` with a `ListView.builder`. without giving definite height and width, the alert dialog is not showing. the list I have is dynamic so I don't want to give a definite height to the listview.builder. And I tried several solutions Like `Singlechildscrollview` `width = double.maxfinite` etc., Nothing worked for me.

When I don't give the height and width this is the exception:

> 'Calculating the intrinsic dimensions would require instantiating
> every child of '
> 'the viewport, which defeats the point of viewports being lazy.',
> 'If you are merely trying to shrink-wrap the viewport in the main axis
> direction, '
> 'you should be able to achieve that effect by just giving the viewport loose '
> 'constraints, without needing to measure its intrinsic dimensions.',

this is my code and I am using getx:

```
Get.defaultDialog(
      title: kLanguageList!.value.clearTask,
      titleStyle: TextStyle(
        color: kBlack,
        fontSize: kTextScaleFactor * 18,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
      textConfirm: kLanguageList!.value.ok,
      confirmTextColor: kBlack,
      textCancel: kLanguageList!.value.cancel,
      cancelTextColor: kOrange,
      buttonColor: Colors.transparent,
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
      onConfirm: () async {
        
      },
      content: Obx(
        () => Container(
          width: double.maxFinite,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: kCancelReasonList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return RadioListTile(
                    toggleable: true,
                    title: CommonText(
                      text: kCancelReasonList[index].name.obs,
                      size: 1,
                      boldText: false,
                    ),
                    value: index,
                    groupValue: selectedreason.value,
                    onChanged: (int? reason) {
                      selectedreason.value = reason!;
                      cancelReason = kCancelReasonList[index].name;
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
              RadioListTile(
                title: CommonText(
                  text: kLanguageList!.value.other.obs,
                  size: 1,
                  boldText: false,
                ),
                value: 3,
                groupValue: selectedreason.value,
                onChanged: (int? reason) {
                  selectedreason.value = reason!;
                },
              ),
              selectedreason.value == 3
                  ? CommonTextFormField(
                      controller: cancelReasonController,
                      onChanged: (reason) {
                        if (reason.isNotEmpty && reason == " ") {
                          cancelReason = reason;
                        }
                      },
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      focusBorderColor: kOrange,
                    )
                  : const SizedBox.shrink(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add height and width based on screen sizeand also add expanded to get the available space and add listview in the expanded widget

```dart
Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.7,
         height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.9,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
             Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: kCancelReasonList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return RadioListTile(
                    toggleable: true,
                    title: CommonText(
                      text: kCancelReasonList[index].name.obs,
                      size: 1,
                      boldText: false,
                    ),
                    value: index,
                    groupValue: selectedreason.value,
                    onChanged: (int? reason) {
                      selectedreason.value = reason!;
                      cancelReason = kCancelReasonList[index].name;
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
              ),
              RadioListTile(
                title: CommonText(
                  text: kLanguageList!.value.other.obs,
                  size: 1,
                  boldText: false,
                ),
                value: 3,
                groupValue: selectedreason.value,
                onChanged: (int? reason) {
                  selectedreason.value = reason!;
                },
              ),
              selectedreason.value == 3
                  ? CommonTextFormField(
                      controller: cancelReasonController,
                      onChanged: (reason) {
                        if (reason.isNotEmpty && reason == " ") {
                          cancelReason = reason;
                        }
                      },
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      focusBorderColor: kOrange,
                    )
                  : const SizedBox.shrink(),
            ],
          ),
```